# jquery ajax post data in php only works for the first time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to delete data using jquery ajax in PHP. I'm able to delete the data for the first time but it doesn't work the second time. It only works when i refresh the page after the first time. I checked the HTML response by ajax to make sure nothing wrong but it still not works. Here is my code.

index.php

```
 <div class="container">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insert">Thêm sinh viên</button>
        <h1 align="center">Bảng sinh viên</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Mã SV</th>
                <th scope="col">Tên</th>
                <th scope="col">SĐT</th>
                <th scope="col">Giới tính</th>
                <th scope="col">Hành động</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="list">
                <?php include('show.php') ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
  $(".delete").on('click',function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var result = confirm("Bạn có muốn xoá sinh viên này không ?");
            if(result){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"delete.php",
                    data: {'id':id},
                    success: function(response){
                        alert("Xoá thành công");
                        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= response;
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

delete.php

```
require_once('db.php');
    $real_id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM students WHERE real_id = ?";
    //DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
    $stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$real_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    include("show.php");
```

show.php

```
$data ="";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $data .="<tr>";
        $data .= "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        $data .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        $data .= "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
        switch ($row['sex']) {
            case "1":
                $sex = "Nam";
                break;
            case "2":
                $sex = "Nữ";
                break;
            case "3":
                $sex = "Khác";
                break;
        }
        $data .= "<td>".$sex."</td>"; 
        $realid = $row['real_id'];
        $data .= "<td><button class='btn btn-danger delete' data-id='$realid'>Xoá</button></td>";
        $data .="</tr>";  
    }
    echo($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your Jquery in to this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.delete',function(){ //<-----
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     var result = confirm("Bạn có muốn xoá sinh viên này không ?");
     if(result){
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:"delete.php",
               data: {'id':id},
               success: function(response){
                    alert("Xoá thành công");
                    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= response;
               }
          })
     }
     return false;
});
```

**Or**
You can do the same but different way:

show.php

```
...

$data .= "<td><button class='btn btn-danger delete' onclick='deleteRecord('$realid')'>Xoá</button></td>";

...
```

And create a Jquery function:

```
function deleteRecord(id){
    var result = confirm("Bạn có muốn xoá sinh viên này không ?");
     if(result){
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:"delete.php",
               data: {'id':id},
               success: function(response){
                    alert("Xoá thành công");
                    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= response;
               }
          })
     }
}
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: Can you pls explain why my code is not running and the way you fix it ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Because in Ajax you removed initially loaded DOM element, so to render click event on new elements you have to reorganize the way how you handle the element what may appear without reload.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending button element to data dynamically.

```
$(".delete").on('click',function() {
 // ..... this will not work second time.
}
```

Try the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete' function(){
 // This should work.
});
```